# What is invoking the super class constructor here?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, superclass, super

I came across this code while looking for exam prep questions.
I don't understand what is invoking the superclass constructor
in this code?

The output is ---> feline cougar cc

THL

```
        public class Feline{

        public String type = "f ";

        public Feline(){
            System.out.print("feline ");
        }
        }
```

-

```
    public class Cougar extends Feline {

    public Cougar(){
            System.out.print("cougar ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            new Cougar().go();                    
    }                                                                                     
    void go(){                            
            type = "c ";                                
            System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's done implicitly before executing the body of the subclass' constructor.

Comment: Add override to suppress super call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a class that extends some other class, eg `Cougar extends Feline`, there *must* be a call to the super class at the top of the constructor. When you don't write one, Java assumes you meant to call the default super class constructor. So your constructor:

```
public Cougar(){
    System.out.print("cougar ");
}
```

Is actually interpreted as:

```
public Cougar(){
     super();
     System.out.print("cougar ");
}
```

Hence the call to the super class constructor. It's interesting to note that because all classes are extensions of the class `Object`, there is a call to a super class constructor at the beginning of every constructor that you'll ever write - either an explicit one you've included with or without arguments, or the default super class constructor if you do not specify.

Comment: Exactly. Only exception of this is if you are calling super() by yourself (maybe to provide some arguments).

Comment: True. I'll clean up my answer to make that more explicit

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler will automatically insert a call to `super()` in this case.  I'd suggest reading over [this Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), specifically this part:

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not include a call to the parents constructor then the parents( no arg ) constructor will get called before the first line of execution in the current class